# python, tkinter, issues while creating bar graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm getting the following error message when I try to create a bars graph, using python and tkinter:

```
AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasTkAgg' object has no attribute 'show'
```

Here's my code

```
import matplotlib,numpy,sys
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
f=Figure(figsize=(5,4),dpi=100)
ax=f.add_subplot(111)
data=(20,35,30,35,27)
ind=numpy.arange(5)  # the x locations for the groups
width=.5
rects1=ax.bar(ind,data,width)
canvas=FigureCanvasTkAgg(f,master=root)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP,fill=BOTH,expand=1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yeah! `FigureCanvasTkAgg` doesn't have `show` function! What you are trying to do?

Comment: thx for answer. i need to insert a bars graph into a tkinter window

Comment: Call `.draw()` instead of `.show()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply delete the line that's causing the problem:

```py
import matplotlib,numpy,sys
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from tkinter import Tk,TOP,BOTH

root=Tk()
f=Figure(figsize=(5,4),dpi=100)
ax=f.add_subplot(111)
data=(20,35,30,35,27)
ind=numpy.arange(5)  # the x locations for the groups
width=.5
rects1=ax.bar(ind,data,width)
canvas=FigureCanvasTkAgg(f,master=root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP,fill=BOTH,expand=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Or replace `.show()` with `.draw()` as @acw1668 mentioned in comment.